Existence of standard part
My favorite proof of the existence of standard part of a limited $x$ in the context of an extension $\mathbb R \subset {}^\ast\hskip-.5pt\mathbb R$ is to say that $x$ defines a Dedekind cut on $\mathbb Q$ (without star); the corresponding real is the standard part of $x$.
Can such an argument be easily expressed in axiomatic approaches to NSA?

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand\std{{}^S}
$Let $L_x = \{q\in\Q\;:\;q\leq x\}$ and $R_x = \{q\in\Q\;:\;q>x\}$ for any $x\in\R$. A standard Dedekind cut is a pair $(L_x, R_x)$ where $x$ is standard.
Let $\std U$ be the standardization of $U\subseteq\Q$, i.e. the unique standard set such that $x\in\std U$ iff $x\in U$ for all standard $x$.
$(\std L_x, \std R_x)$ is a standard Dedekind cut for arbitrary finite $x\in\R$; so there is a unique standard $x'\in\mathbb R$ such that $(\std L_x,\std R_x) = (L_{x'}, R_{x'})$, and we define this to be the standard part of $x$. The proof is as follows:
What we want to show for $L_x$ is
$$
  \exists^\sigma x'.\forall q\in\Q.\:q\leq x'\iff q\in\std L_x
$$
where $\exists^\sigma,\forall^\sigma$ denote quantification over standard elements. Suppose this were not the case. Then
$$
  \forall^\sigma x'.\exists q\in\Q.\:(q>x'\land q\in\std L_x)\lor(q\leq x'\land q\not\in\std L_x).
$$
By Transfer we can assume $q$ is standard, and thus
$$
  \forall^\sigma x'.\exists^\sigma q\in\Q.\: (x'<q\leq x)\lor(x<q\leq x')
$$
but this contradicts $x$ being finite. This shows that $\std L_x = L_{x'}$ for some standard $x'$, and a similar argument shows that $\std R_x = R_{x''}$ for some standard $x''$. Now since $(L_x, R_x)$ partitions $\mathbb Q$, it also partitions the standard elements of $\Q$, and by Transfer $(L_{x'}, R_{x''})$ partitions $\mathbb Q$. Thus $x' = x''$.

Here is another proof that is arguably more straightforward (at least it doesn't use contradiction):
$(L_x, R_x)$ partitions $\Q$, which is to say
$$
  \forall q\in\Q.\:q\in L_x\text{ xor }q\in R_x.
$$
We can restrict the quantifier to standard rationals (written $\forall^\sigma$), whence
$$
  \forall^\sigma q\in\Q.\:q\in\std L_x\text{ xor }q\in\std R_x
$$
but then Transfer applies and so $(\std L_x, \std R_x)$ partitions $\Q$.
Now consider the fact that
$$
  \forall q\in L_x.\forall q'\in R_x.\:q<q'.
$$
The same exact argument shows that this applies to $(\std L_x, \std R_x)$. So this is a Dedekind cut, or one of $\std L_x, \std R_x$ is empty. But since $x$ is finite there are standard $q, q'\in\Q$ such that $q<x<q'$ and so $q\in\std L_x$ and $q'\in\std R_x$. Thus $(\std L_x, \std R_x)$ is a Dedekind cut, and by Transfer is a standard Dedekind cut as desired.

This last proof shows something quite interesting: if we remove the requirement that $x$ be finite, then we get the extended reals! The standard part of every nonstandard infinite negative real is $-\infty := (\varnothing, \mathbb Q)$, and standard part of the positive ones is $\infty := (\mathbb Q,\varnothing)$.

Thanks.  One can also apply (countable) standardisation to the set of ranks where digit $1$ appears in the binary representation of $x$, which works in SPOT.
